# Simpy subway simulation: how to fix interrupt failure of class train while queueing for a resource?

Tags: simulation, reliability, simpy

I am working on a train simulation in simpy and have had success so far with a single train entity following the code below.

The trains processes are sections followed by platforms. Each section and platform has a resource of 1 to ensure that only one train utilises at a time.

However I can't find a way to get around the error below:

When I add in a second train to the simulation there is occasionally the situation where one train waits for an unavailable resource and then a failure occurs on that train while it is waiting.

I end up with an *Interrupt: Interrupt()* error.

Is there a way around these failing queues for resources?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
import random
import simpy
import numpy

# Configure parameters for the model
RANDOM_SEED = random.seed() # makes results repeatable

T_MEAN_SECTION = 200.0 # journey time (seconds)

DWELL_TIME = 30.0 # dwell time mean (seconds)
DWELL_TIME_EXPO = 1/DWELL_TIME # for exponential distribution

MTTF = 600.0  # mean time to failure (seconds)
TTF_MEAN = 1/MTTF # for exponential distribution

REPAIR_TIME = 120.0 # mean repair time for when failure occurs (seconds)
REPAIR_TIME_EXPO = 1/REPAIR_TIME # for exponential distribution

NUM_TRAINS = 2 # number of trains to simulate

SIM_TIME_HOURS = 1 # sim time in hours
SIM_TIME_DAYS = SIM_TIME_HOURS/18.0 # number of days to simulate
SIM_TIME = 3600 * 18 * SIM_TIME_DAYS # sim time in seconds (this is used in the code below)


# Defining the times for processes
def Section(): # returns processing time for platform 7 Waterloo to 26 Bank
    return T_MEAN_SECTION

def Dwell(): # returns processing time for platform 25 Bank to platform 7 Waterloo
    return random.expovariate(DWELL_TIME_EXPO)

def time_to_failure(): # returns time until next failure
    return random.expovariate(TTF_MEAN)



# Defining the train
class Train(object):

    def __init__(self, env, name, repair):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.trips_complete = 0
        self.num_saf = 0
        self.sum_saf = 0
        self.broken = False

    # Start "running" and "downtime_train" processes for the train
        self.process = env.process(self.running(repair))
        env.process(self.downtime_train())  


    def running(self, repair):

        while True:

            # request section A
            request_SA = sectionA.request()

########## SIM ERROR IF FAILURE OCCURS HERE ###########
            yield request_SA

            done_in_SA = Section()          
            while done_in_SA:

                try:
                    # going on the trip
                    start = self.env.now


                    print('%s leaving platform at time %d') % (self.name, env.now)

                    # processing time
                    yield self.env.timeout(done_in_SA)

                    # releasing the section resource
                    sectionA.release(request_SA)
                    done_in_SA = 0 # Set to 0 to exit while loop

                except simpy.Interrupt:
                    self.broken = True
                    delay = random.expovariate(REPAIR_TIME_EXPO)
                    print('Oh no! Something has caused a delay of %d seconds to %s at time %d') % (delay, self.name, env.now)
                    done_in_SA -= self.env.now - start # How much time left?
                    with repair.request(priority = 1) as request_D_SA:
                        yield request_D_SA
                        yield self.env.timeout(delay)
                    self.broken = False
                    print('Okay all good now, failure fixed on %s at time %d') % (self.name, env.now)
                    self.num_saf += 1
                    self.sum_saf += delay



            # request platform A
            request_PA = platformA.request()

########## SIM ERROR IF FAILURE OCCURS HERE ###########
            yield request_PA

            done_in_PA = Dwell()
            while done_in_PA:

                try:

                    # platform process
                    start = self.env.now


                    print('%s arriving to platform A and opening doors at time %d') % (self.name, env.now)
                    yield self.env.timeout(done_in_PA)
                    print('%s closing doors, ready to depart platform A at %d\n') % (self.name, env.now)
                    # releasing the platform resource
                    platformA.release(request_PA)
                    done_in_PA = 0 # Set to 0 to exit while loop

                except simpy.Interrupt:
                    self.broken = True
                    delay = random.expovariate(REPAIR_TIME_EXPO)
                    print('Oh no! Something has caused a delay of %d seconds to %s at time %d') % (delay, self.name, env.now)
                    done_in_PA -= self.env.now - start # How much time left?
                    with repair.request(priority = 1) as request_D_PA:
                        yield request_D_PA
                        yield self.env.timeout(delay)
                    self.broken = False
                    print('Okay all good now, failure fixed on %s at time %d') % (self.name, env.now)
                    self.num_saf += 1
                    self.sum_saf += delay


        # Round trip is finished

            self.trips_complete += 1


# Defining the failure event        
    def downtime_train(self):
        while True:
            yield self.env.timeout(time_to_failure())
            if not self.broken:
            # Only break the train if it is currently working
                self.process.interrupt()



# Setup and start the simulation
print('Train trip simulator')
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED) # Helps with reproduction

# Create an environment and start setup process
env = simpy.Environment()

# Defining resources 
platformA = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)
sectionA = simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 1)

repair = simpy.PreemptiveResource(env, capacity = 10)

trains = [Train(env, 'Train %d' % i, repair)
    for i in range(NUM_TRAINS)]


# Execute
env.run(until = SIM_TIME)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your processes request a resource and never release it.  That’s why the second trains waits forever for its request to succeed.  While it is waiting, the failure process seems to interrupt the process.  That’s why you get an error.  Please read the [guide to resources](http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topical_guides/resources.html) to understand how SimPy’s resources work and, especially, how to release a resource when you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stefan. However the resource is released in the while try: part below where it is requested. This seems to work fine as trains go around the two processes nicely in a loop.... until a failure occurs on one of the trains if it is queueing for a resource.

Comment: Okay, now I can see where you release the requests.  The problem still is that a train, while it is waiting for request_SA or request_PA gets interrupted by the failure process.  You can wrap the `yield request_SA` with a `try ... except simpy.Interrupt: pass` to ignore it, for example.